# Can not Truncate the database because “secondaries has no log was added”

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, transaction-log, high-availability

I am a newbie to SQL Server. I got an error when trying to truncate the database:

> Database can not shrink until all secondaries have moved past the point where the log was added.

When I check the status of the secondary on the primary machine (Always On High Availability Dashboard), it has

> heath: good and
> Synchronization state: Synchronizing.

But the status of database on secondary is NULL not ONLINE. When I check on the Always On High Availability of the Secondary machine, it's state is No data available on secondary replicas.

**Question:** What should I do and what is going on with the database..?
(I want to truncate because the free space is no more enough. I use E:\ for all databases file has used 421.5Gb and free 78.5Gb.)

Here is the nearly I check the status wiht the query below with two result on primary machine(pic 1) and secondary machine(pic 2):

```
SELECT d.name, r.replica_server_name, ars.role_desc, ars.operational_state_desc,
        drs.synchronization_state_desc, ars.connected_state_desc,
        drs.last_hardened_lsn, d.log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.availability_databases_cluster AS adc 
JOIN sys.databases AS d ON adc.group_database_id = d.group_database_id 
JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS drs ON d.database_id = drs.database_id 
JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS r ON drs.replica_id = r.replica_id 
JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars ON r.replica_id = ars.replica_id
```

[image: This is the result on Primary machine]
[image: This is the result on Secondary machine]

I have tried suspending, off and re-join the secondary replica databases on the secondary machine (APEX-SQL2) but nothing has change...

> Additionally, I ran 3 query below:
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

*Thank you for reading. Pls help..*

Comment: Run a TLog backup on the primary, give it a few minutes, run a second TLog backup, and then retry your `DBCC` operation.

Comment: I could not do it right now because the disk space for backup is not enough. Is there more hope for me?

Comment: How big is the drive the database files live on?...how much space is free on it currently? What does `EXEC sp_spaceused` return when ran in the context of the database in question? What is the Recovery Model of the database? What does `SELECT [name], log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases` return? Please add all the answers to these questions to your Post.

Comment: Thankyou J.D, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suspend database synchronization on the secondary node.
2. Delete the database from the availability group on the secondary
   node.
3. Create a transaction log backup on the primary node.
4. Disable automatic transaction log backup on both nodes.
5. Restore all transaction logs to the secondary database to bring it
   up-to-date.
6. Add the database back to the availability group.

Comment: I will try it thank you so much.